# Cakephp Pagination URL

Tags: cakephp

I am facing a problem in cake php pagination. In my project I have Category Suppose 'Wooden' , In this I have Sub Category as 'Wooden Tables' and further 'Wooden tables' has many products. In sub category i am doing pagination . I am showing 10 items per page. Now the problem is that When i click on any of the pagination link , its missing sub category number. for example : the URL should look like this : **http://amazingtech.in/lariya/products/index/4/page:2** but when i click on pagination link the URL look like this http://amazingtech.in/lariya/products/index/page:2 . It is missing the sub **category number 4** , which leads to page not found error. and when i manually enter the URL Like this  . It works.

```
I don't know how to modify pagination URL. Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

Pagination - that is selecting or sorting results - isn't the same as searching for them by criteria, even though Cake supports passing them as an array or named params. That is to say, conditions of your find() are not preserved in the same way as your pagination params.

So You'd need to include your condition as a named or query parameter: eg: assuming your category is 'category' (it might be category_id, replace as needed)

```
http://amazingtech.in/lariya/products/index/category:1234/page:2
```

Or possibly:

```
http://amazingtech.in/lariya/products/index/category:Wooden/page:2 //more SEO friendly
```

Or even:

```
http://amazingtech.in/lariya/products/index/4/page:2
http://amazingtech.in/lariya/products/index/Wooden/page:2 //more SEO friendly
```

To do it this last way you'll need to setup your controller to look for the first URL param in and assign it as a condition of your find() operation:

```
public function index($category = null) { 
    $conditions = array('Products.category_id' => $category);
    ...etc
}
```

MORE: [CakePHP Cookbook Parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#request-parameters)

That way, when you paginate - as long as you're going through the same controller - can preserve that category.

Comment: hi, can u pls explain a little bit, i am still confused , how to do this. I want to create Url somthing like this :  http://amazingtech.in/lariya/products/index/4/page:2  or 
http://amazingtech.in/lariya/products/index/Wooden/page:2 //more SEO friendly